# Seq2seq with attention model only predicts index 0 in a text generation task

Tags: natural-language-processing, tensorflow, seq2seq

I am trying to build a model which summarizes some brief input text (X) and generates a headline (Y).

The problem is that the model always outputs 0 as the vocabulary index, which I think that might be due to sentence padding, I have tried to use mask_zero parameter in the embedding layer but results are the same.

I also have considered that the problem might be that I have very little data to train the network but I supposed it would fail in some manner but outputing random words, not always 0.

The network architecture I am trying to use is a seq2seq Bi-LSTM with attention mechanism and I am using Glove 50D embeddings as input layer.

Basically the model is based in three code functions that comprehend the previously explained model.

A good visual representation of the model is the following from Andrew Ng just substituting one hot vector inputs with embeddings in the input layer:

[image: Full model structure]

1. Model layers definition at global scope to share weights

```
# Attention layers globally defined
repeator = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(Tx)
concatenator = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh')
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
activator = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax', name="attention_weights")
dotor = tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=1)

# Post-attention LSTM globally defined to share weights
post_attention_LSTM = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=n_s, return_state=True)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
```

2. Full model structure:

```
def seq2seq_clickbait(Tx, Ty, n_a, n_s, vocab_size, emb_size):

    # Define Model Inputs
    sentence_indices = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(Tx,), dtype='int32')

    emb_matrix = build_embeddings_matrix(word_to_vec, vocab_size, word_to_idx, emb_size)

    pretrained_embedding = pretrained_embedding_layer(emb_matrix, vocab_size, emb_size)

    embeddings = pretrained_embedding(sentence_indices)

    s0 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
    c0 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')

    s = s0
    c = c0

    outputs = []

    a = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=n_a, return_sequences=True))(embeddings)

    for t in range(Ty):

        # Once we have a, we can get the context to pass it to the post attention lstm time step
        context = one_step_attention(a, s)

        # Get current states from post-attention lstm
        s, _, c = post_attention_LSTM(inputs=context, initial_state=[s, c])

        # Apply dense (softmax vocab_size)
        out = output_layer(inputs=s)
        outputs.append(out)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[sentence_indices, s0, c0], outputs=outputs)

    return model
```

A good visual representation of what does one_step_attention(a, s)

[image]

3. context

```
def one_step_attention(a, s_prev):

    # Repeat the s_prev vector Tx times to expand the vector
    s_prev = repeator(s_prev)

    # Concatenate a and s_prev
    concat = concatenator([a, s_prev])

    # Forward prop to a dense layer
    e = dense_1(concat)

    energies = dense_2(e)

    # Apply softmax to energies to get the alphas
    alphas = activator(energies)

    # Get context from the alphas
    context = dotor([alphas, a])

    return context
```

I present the outputs to the model as a one hot vector so if the ouput sentence is length (Ty) 20 the output tensor is (20, m, vocab_size). My guess is that many of the labeled sentences are not length 20 and therefore they are padded, so the network is learning to output 0's since it is a pretty good way of improving accuracy / decrease loss in short senteces widely padded.

If half of the output steps of the network are filled with a [1, 0, 0,..., 0] one hot vector which represents the 0 index (pad) it dense layer will learn to output probabilities distributions like [0.8, 0.002, 0.00003, ....] selecting the 0 index.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you in advance

## EDIT

Some additional info about the model.

loss function is categorical_crossentropy, I have not added extra tokens to the vocabulary given by GloVe embeddings, I removed 'PAD' as a vocabulary token since TF embeddings docs says so when mask_zero=True. m is the number of examples, Tx and Ty is the sentence max length of X and Y, n_s is the number of post-attention LSTM units and n_a is Bi-LSTM units. I think indeed is a masking problem but mask_zero=True is not solving it. It only works with return_sequences=True and post att LSTM has return_squences=False because it loops through steps.

Comment: What loss function are you using, can you post it? What kind of extra tokens are you using? PAD, EOS, UNK, ... ? Can you name your variables (m, Tx, Ty, n_a, n_s)?

It sounds most likely like a masking issue, because your model thinks that 0 (i.e. PAD) is the most likely token. Remember that you have to mask twice: in the model, and in the loss. Padding is only necessary for under-the-hood time-wise optimisation when passing mini-batches. The neural network should never actually "compute" on the padding tokens, unless it is important to predict them.

Comment: loss function is categorical_crossentropy, I have not added extra tokens to the vocabulary given by GloVe embeddings, I removed 'PAD' as a vocabulary token since TF embeddings docs says so when mask_zero=True. m is the number of examples, Tx and Ty is the sentence max length of X and Y, n_s is the number of post-attention LSTM units and n_a is Bi-LSTM units. I think indeed is a masking problem but mask_zero=True is not solving it. It only works with return_sequences=True and post att LSTM has return_squences=False because it loops through steps. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: So what is PAD then encoded as if it is not in the vocabulary? I don't get it. You also should have a GO token and an EOS token for the decoder of the seq2seq. Sequences go from GO + sentence -> sentence + EOS. You need GO to tell the model the sentence starts (see here for a visual: https://doi.org/10.1145/3419106).

And the way you talk about masking makes me think you rely too much on keras taking care of it for you. To my knowledge, you only need to mask the RNN computation and attention.

Comment: The fact that the model predicts the padding token as the most likely one means that there is also a mistake in your loss. With crossentropy, you will do sth like loss(logits, targets), but you should only do that for the non-padding tokens in your target. Hence, when you accumulate the loss, make sure to multiply it by zero once you reach the padding tokens in your mini-batch. Also make sure you understand what this means for averaging the loss over the sequence length.

If your problem persists, I advise you to post a link to your whole code.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the loss function is taking into account Y label`s padding since last steps of the dense layer's output (padding) get high accuracy / low loss but first steps ar low accuracy / high loss and therefore the network learns to ouput 0 as the most probable index for every step. I will look deeper into masking the Y label's padding to the loss function and probably also acquire more data. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: You're welcome! I would postpone looking for more data, however. Do you have a script to overfit? That's usually the first sanity test, to see if you can just learn 1 or 2 sequences. It's fast, and you can spot errors much easier.